# bottle + nginx: connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: python, nginx, centos, bottle

I'm receiving tons of the following errors in my nginx error log:

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

My app is otherwise working fine and if I try to access the urls from the log they all show ok in the browser but I still want to track down the source of those errors.

I've tried enabling keep alive in my nginx config but it didn't change anything.

```
location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
    }
```

My server is running CentOS 7.6, Python 2.7.5, bottle 0.13-dev and nginx 1.12.2.

It's a bottle web app using gevent server:

```py
bottle.run(app=myapp, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=False, quiet=True, reloader=False, server='gevent')
```

This my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *****;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    root  /usr/local/*****;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    location /static {
    }

    location /protected {
        internal;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/*****/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/*****/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    # include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

Could it be that simply gevent and bottle are not processing the requests fast enough and giving temporary connection refused errors? Should I try with another server like uWSGI or maybe with some nginx proxy optimisations?

Answer (score 0):

I use bottle with nginx and works fine, i handle the load with gunicorn wsgi server and it works realy good, i try using just

```
python3 app.py
```

Works fine i recoment you to use this code to setup the bottle server

```
import bottle
from bottle import run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='localhost', port=8080)
application = bottle.default_app()
```

And i think is better to finish the proxy pass with / like this

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080/;
}
```